# OnItemSelectedListener in a Fragment that uses a custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

So I've been playing around with this for a few days now and just can't seem to get it to work.  I've got an Activity that displays a Fragment and that Fragment is a member of a list of Fragments that I page through using ViewPager.  The Fragment itself is comprised of a TextView and a ListView.  The ListView populates itself from a custom Adapter.

What I'm trying to do is pass an OnItemSelected event back to the Fragment where it is handled.  It's probably better for me to just go ahead and show code here.

This is the Activity

```
public class DialogInventory extends FragmentActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

ViewPager viewPager;
Pager pager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_inventory);

    List<Fragment> fragList = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragList.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentOne.class.getName()));
    fragList.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentTwo.class.getName()));
    pager = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragList);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerMain);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pager);

    listMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMain);
    listMain.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    switch (viewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
        case 0:
            FragmentOne fragOne = new FragmentOne();
            fragOne.onItemSelected(parent, view, pos, id);
            break;
        case 1:
            FragmentTwo fragTwo = new FragmentTwo();
            fragTwo.onItemSelected(parent, view, pos, id);
            break;
    }
}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
}
```

This is the Fragment:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener {

View view;
ListView listMain;
ArrayList<String> invItems = new ArrayList<String>();

public FragmentOne() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, viewGroup, false);

    listMain = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listMain);
    listMain.setAdapter(new AdapterItem(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
        R.layout.tile_item, invItems));
    listMain.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    return view;
}
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    Log.i("Test", "hit");
}
```

Some lines are omitted for brevity.  Lets go on the assumption that the Fragments get displayed correctly and that everything works.  The only thing that isn't working correctly is that the OnItemSelected event in the Activity is not firing at all...much less the OnItemSelected event in the fragment.  What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: the ListViews must be in their respective Fragments (as they will be displayed individually in a different Activity as well as the one listed above).  The biggest issue here is that I can't set an OnItemSelectedListener in my Activity, therefore the event never gets fired off.  I have all the code leading up to that point worked out and running, it's just the OnItemSelectedListener that doesn't work.

Edit2: I will be adding a bounty to this question tomorrow.  In light of that I thought I would be more implicit on the scope of a correct answer.  A correct answer would not suggest any dramatic changes to UI layout or presentation.  The correct answer will pass an OnItemSelected event to the Fragment and be handled there.  The answer would not have me load my Activity down with line after line of code to achieve something that I feel is do-able with only a few lines.  The more elegant answers are obviously more appealing.  Thank you to anyone who takes a look at this.

The problem here is that I get an NPE in my activity.  How do I point it to a ListView that exists in a different layout than the Layout of the class it's in.

Comment: Running the risk of breaking your "I dont want to change the UI" rule, is there a reason you are not using a `ListFragment` which by default gives you a method to `Override` that catches clicks on a `ListView` and thus you can do what I believe you are trying to do, which is to handle the list item clicks locally in the fragment...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView, android.view.View, int, long)

Comment: yes, because the ListFragment fills the whole screen.  In this case I will have buttons at the bottom, and a title TextView at the top

Comment: You seem to have things back to front: you shouldn't be trying to catch the list item clicks in the activity and propagate them to the fragment(s), but rather receive them in the relevant fragment directly. Basically @SalilPandit has given the correct approach. Whether you use a `ListFragment` or not is up to you, but your assumption that it "fills the whole" screen isn't correct; it's just  a convenience fragment for dealing with lists, but you can make it look like whatever you want, provided you at least declare one `ListView` with `@android:id/list`.

Comment: @MH. has it right. you can have any layout as long as the `ListView` has the id `@android:id/list`. and then it will be accessible from getListView() as long as you inflate it in your `onCreateView` method...

Comment: Thank you for the input.  I will try to use a listFragment and see how it works out.  As long as you don't have to use a UI that only include a listView then I don't see any reason not to use it.

Comment: Please provide code.  I have 5 hours from this posting to award the rep points.  In 4 hours the closest answer gets it.

Answer (score 2):

Where do you use `listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)`?  You need to explicitly inform the ListView that your Activity should control the UI behaviors...

And in your Fragment add:

```
listMain.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: Ooops.  left that out.  Editing op

Comment: Ok, now you need to find your ListView in the Activity (with `(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView)`), set the adapter and do the same.

Comment: I just gave it a try.  Now I'm getting NPE on setting the listener to the listview in the activity.  I'll update the OP with code changes

Comment: Post your dialog_inventory.xml. The id passed to findViewById() **must** be in the layout passed to setContentView(), also don't forget to set an adapter.

Comment: The id isn't in there, its in the XML that the Fragment uses.  Is there a way to look for it there instead?  If I move the ListView to the Activity's XML then that would make using a fragment kind of pointless, right?  Update OP to include XML

Comment: If you only want one ListView, then yes trying to code it twice is silly. I'm guessing that you only want the one in your Activity, so simply cut & paste everything over.

Comment: Each Fragment has it's own ListView in this case, and some of the Fragments I will be displaying don't have a ListView.  Also, the Adapter being used for each Fragment's ListView is different as well...so getting the Activity to see the ListView in the Fragment instead of looking in it's own XML is kind of important.  Thanks again for your input, this is helping a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help. I must admit I am a little confused by your last comment: if I have answered your original question please check off my answer, if you need more help post more code, any logcat errors, and describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: Let me clarify.  Basically the ListView can't be in the Activity because each ListView is unique.  The ListView in FragmentOne uses it's own element XML and populates with one set of data, while the ListView in FragmentTwo uses a different XML file for elements and a different data set.  Each Fragment gets instantiated and put into the ViewPager so that the user can transition from one to the other at run time.  Is there a way to make the Activity see the ListView in the Fragment instead of looking for it in it's own View.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14017/discussion-between-sam-and-user1449018)

Comment: Sorry I had to leave the chat.  I'll keep messing around with this and post the results for interested parties should I figure something out.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own interface and Callback is probably the best solution. In my app I did something like this :

```
public class ModuleFragment extends ListFragment {
   //...
    private OnModuleSelectedListener mdListener;

// this method makes sure my activity implements my interface. If not I show an error
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mdListener = (OnModuleSelectedListener) activity;
            Log.d(TAG, "OnModuleSelectedListener Implemented !");
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnSqSelectedListener");
        }
    }
// This is the standard onListItemClick, I use it to get data I need and give them to the Listener
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        l.getItemAtPosition(position);
        HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) l
            .getItemAtPosition(position);
        mdId = map.get("id");
        mdName = map.get("name");
        mdListener.onModuleSelected(mdId,mdName);

    }

    public interface OnModuleSelectedListener {
        public void onModuleSelected(String mdId, String mdName);
    }
}
```

Here's now my activity :

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnModuleSelectedListener{
//...
    public void onModuleSelected(String mdId, String mdName) {
            //.. I do whatever I want with what I get from the list
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you a bit. That's the closest answer to your question I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

I've also been trying to do something similar to this.  The problem lies in the fact that you don't have an instance in the activity with which to set an onitemselected listener.  I, personally, tried everything that I could think of to get this to work.  Including:

```
list = (ListView) vp.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.listMain);
list.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Where list is a listview you instantiate then set to the list in the fragment.  The problem with this approach is that you get an NPE when you try to set the listener to this.  If you find an answer to this please, please, please post it here.  It would help me a ton.

I've had people suggest that I take a new approach and just re-create the list each time the viewpager is called (without actually paging..i.e. creating the illusion of a swipe when in actuality the view never changes) and I've had people suggest using a ListFragment...  ListFragment would be nice, but then you can't include anything else in your layout except a ListFragment.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  Sam (above) and I worked on this for a bit and tried several solutions but nothing seems to work.  I'm almost thinking that Android doesn't support function like this.  My hard-headedness tells me that I'm wrong though, and this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

In your FragmentActivity, instead of use OnItemSelectedListener, perhaps you can use a static method to do the job. And call this method in **onItemSelected()** (in fragment).

Answer (score 0):

Implement an Interface in the parent activity of the fragment will solve your issue. For example. The TestFragment contains a interface called TestFragmentListener. Implement this listener interface in your parent activity and hold the reference of the Interface in the Fragment to do the callback.OnItemSelectedListener method do the callback to the parent activity and handle the rest as normal. Please refer to the sample code below.

```
public final class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView title;
    ListView listView;
    TestFragmentListener mActivity;
    TestAdapter adapter;

    public interface TestFragmentListener {
        public void onItemSelected(Object o);
    }

    public static TestFragment newInstance(String content) {
        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

        try {
            mActivity = (TestFragmentListener) activity;

        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            Log.e("Invalid listerer", e.getMessage());
        }

        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mActivity = null;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);

        title = (TextView) vw.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        listView = (ListView) vw.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        return vw;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter();

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                mActivity.onItemSelected(arg2);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

---

```
private class TestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 100;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {

            TextView tv = new TextView((Activity) mActivity);
            tv.setText(Integer.toString(position));
            return tv;
        }
    }

}
```